# checking if a function is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How can i prove that the following function is differentiable?
$$f(x_1,x_2)=\int_0^{|x_1|}g(s)ds+x_2^2$$
where $g(x)$ is an increasing function with $g(0)=0$.

Its partial derivative is equal to $\frac{\partial f(x_1,x_2)}{x_1}=g(|x_1|)\frac{\partial |x_1|}{\partial x_1}$, isn't there a problem at $x_1=0$?

Comment: The formula you've written for the partial derivative with respect to the first coordinate only holds if $x_1\neq 0$. For $x_1=0$ you need to use the definition.

Comment: If the partial derivatives of a function f exist and are continuous around a point "a", then the function is differentiable at "a". By taking into account that, can i conclude that the function f defined above is differentiable at 0? what if i define that the partial derivative wrt the first variable is equal to zero?

Comment: Your plan for proving $f$'s differentiability,but you can't just decide what the partial derivatives at the origin are. They are what they are, you need to find'em. It's not something you can decide.

Comment: yeah, you are absolutely right!i'm rally frustrated with this one.. but how can i use the definition since the absolute value is not differentiable at zero. the only thing i can think about is taking the limit as x approaches 0 so tthat $\partial f/\partial x_1\rightarrow 0$, but in order to do that i must have that $\partial |x_1|/\partial x_1$ is bounded.

Comment: I meant "Your plan for proving $f$'s differentiability looks good". You're not thinking correctly, the definition at a point $(0,y_0)$ of the partial with respect to first coordinate is $\lim \limits_{h\to 0}\left(\dfrac{f(0+h,y_0)-f(0,y_0)}{h}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

We only have to check at which points $x\in{\mathbb R}$ the function
$$f(x):=\int_0^{|x|} g(s)\>ds$$
is differentiable. As $g$ is monotonically increasing it has one-sided limits $$g(x-)\leq g(x)\leq g(x+)$$ at all points $x$. If $x\ne0$ and $g$ is continuous at $|x|$ then
$$f'(x)={\rm sgn}(x)\>g\bigl(|x|\bigr)\ .$$
Consider now a point $x>0$ with $g(x-)<g(x)$. Then
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\int_x^{x+h} g(s)\>ds\geq g(x+)\>h\ ,$$
which implies
$$\lim_{h\to0+}\inf{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}\geq g(x+)\ .$$
In a similar way one proves
$$\lim_{h\to0-}\sup{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}\leq g(x-)\ .$$
This shows that $f$ is not differentiable at discontinuities $x\ne0$ of $g$.

It remains to check what happens at $x=0$. Here $f$ is differentiable iff $g(0+)=0$. I leave the proof to you.